# How to match two words if they are within a sentence/paragraph using Azure Search?

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search on top of a CosmosDB database and we are switching to full search (Lucene) to be able to support more advanced search scenarios.

One of the search requirements we have is to match 2 words if they both exist in a sentence or paragraph. Something like the following will go into the searchbox:

word1 /p word2

This is doable using regular expressions. However, I am not sure how to implement this in Azure-search/Lucene. Azure-search Lucene supports RegEx search but as it says here, it only matches single words.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

To wrap up, is there any way we can implement [word1 /p word2] using Azure-search Lucene syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a exact match using quotes will find  instances of “word1 word2”.

Alternatively you could use the proximity search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_proximity

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment Dashleen. As per my understanding, proximity search can be used to match word1 and word2 if they are located within n words of each-other. It does not take into account if they are within the same paragraph or sentence. Word1 and word2 could be within 5 words of each other but in different sentences. That should not be a match. Makes sense?

Comment: Consider indexing each sentence/paragraph as an independent element of a string collection. Otherwise, there are no query operators that allow you to achieve what you want. 

The documentation about regex is not specific enough. The pattern doesn’t need to much a single word, but a single term. If the content of a fields is indexed as one term (use keyword analyzer), you can write a regex expression that will match on the entire content. This will be incredibly inefficient and you’ll run into max term length limits (32,766 B). Thus, I recommend the first solution.